# Problem comparing strings containing numbers

Tags: c, string, comparison

hello i got a problem with comparing two char* variables that contains numbers for example
`char1 = "999999"` and `char2="11111111"`
when i am using the `strcmp` function it will return that char1 variable is greater than char2
even tho its wrong.
(i know that i can compare with using the atoi function till 9 chars inside the string but i need to use 10 so it cuts this possibility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly more cumbersome way, that avoids `atoi` and friends, is to prefix the shorter of the two strings with zeroes. Or, assuming there are no prefixing zeroes, simply first comparing the length (since shorter strings must have a lower value), then running a lexiographic comparison:

```
int numerical_strcmp(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return (strlen(a) != strlen(b)) ? ((strlen(a) > strlen(b)) ? 1 : -1) : strcmp(a, b);
}
```

Oh, and this requires the strings to contain non-negative numbers.

Comment: you should have at least cached strlen() results in a variable.

Comment: btw, I often do `int x = (strlen(a) - strlen(b));` as to spare one variable.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's right.  It's doing a string comparison of the contents of the strings, not a numeric one.

As a quick and dirty hack, assuming that you've already validated that the strings contain positive integers, you could do the following:

```
if (strlen(char2) > strlen(char1)) {
  // char2 > char1
} else if (strlen(char2) == strlen(char1)) {
  cmp = strcmp(char2, char1);
  if (cmp > 0) {
    // char2 > char 1
  } else if (cmp == 0) {
    // char2 == char1
  } else {
    // char2 < char1
  }
} else {
  // char2 < char1
}
```

Comment: is there a way to compare it according to the numeric value of the string ? 
cause this is what i need for my comperisson

Comment: Yes - see above.  If one string's longer or shorter than the other, then that alone determines the answer; if they're the same length, then an strcmp() can be used.

Answer (score 3):

If the strings have no leading/trailing garbage, use this algorithm:

- Compare the lengths of the two strings using `strlen()`. The longer one is always the biggest.
- If the length are equal, use `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to a 64-bit integer using [`_atoi64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czcad93k(VS.80).aspx).  Then, you can just compare them directly as you'd expect.  Depending on your compiler, `_atoi64` might be called something different.

Answer (score 1):

shortest way should be:

```
int mystrcmp(const char *a,const char *b)
{
  return strlen(a)-strlen(b)?strlen(a)-strlen(b):strcmp(a,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ordered literally, which means that something starting on 9 will always be greater than something starting on 1. If you need to do an integer comparison, you'll have to use atoi.

Comment: i cant use atoi cause my string can have 10 chars inside it 
and the atoi / atol would not work